# Why when I convert a pdf file to csv using the tabula package I get an empty csv file?

Tags: python, csv, pdf, import, tabula

when i convert pdf file to csv file using tabula packege i get a empty csv file
here the code:

```
import tabula
df = tabula.read_pdf('/content/blood_test_1.pdf', pages='all')
tabula.convert_into('/content/blood_test_1.pdf', '/content/test.csv' , output_format="csv",pages='all', stream=True)
```

Comment: Try `df = tabula.read_pdf('/content/blood_test_1.pdf', pages='all', stream=True)`, also see https://tabula-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#i-got-a-empty-dataframe-how-can-i-resolve-it

Comment: did df contain any data? (i.e before writing to csv i mean), if not then most likely we need the pdf to try with.